# Substring in SQL reverts back false syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I need to extract the two numbers after decimal point.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(project_code AS varchar(20)), CHARINDEX('.', CAST(project_code AS varchar(max)), 2)) 
FROM
    projects
```

Comment: What RDBMS?  What is the actual error message?  Maybe some sample data?  just a guess - are there `project_code` values that don't contain a period?

Comment: yes, there are some values that do not contain a period.

Comment: Error is in the syntax, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error number `1064` that you mentioned in your original question seems like a MySql error, although you are using the function `CHARINDEX()` which works in SQL Server.
If you are using MySql you can do what you want with the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT substring_index(project_code, '.', -1)
FROM projects
```

This code will extract everything after the `'.'`.
If you want exactly 2 chars then use this:

```
SELECT left(substring_index(project_code, '.', -1), 2)
FROM projects
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can you also let me know how to get the characters *before* the decimal point?

Comment: It would be: `substring_index(project_code, '.', 1)`

Comment: Is it possible to use  if conditions with insert? Like, insert *this* if *condition 1* else insert *that* ?

Comment: This is possible depending on the requirement. Post a question where you explain what you want to do.